# Check if int is defined as macro. C

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I've tried to check around, but I can't seem to find an answer.

I'm writing some C code, and I want to figure out if given `int i`, is that defined as a macro somewhere. For instance, running a `for` loop checking if the counter is a macro. I've come up with the following, but it give me warnings when I compile, so I'm assuming its bad code

```
for(int i = 1; i < 25; i++){
   #define DEFINED 1
   #ifndef i
   #define DEFINED 0
   #endif
   int a = DEFINED;
   if(a){
      bla bla
   }
}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: *it gives a lot of errors*.  **What** errors, specifically?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why would you want to do that? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: actually i meant warnings, that im redefining a macro. And im not sure why i wrote alot, because it is only one warning

Comment: The way to discover macro definitions depends on your compiler. What compiler is it?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: You can't use the *value* of `i` as a condition in a preprocessor expression. You can't even check if it's defined.

Longer answer: preprocessing is one of the early translation stages. It happens even before the code is compiled. The value of `i` is available only during run time. Meaning after the program has been compiled, linked, and then executed. The two stages are as far apart as they can be.

You can't check if an `i` variable is defined either, since the symbol `i` is known as a variable only during the compilation stage (again, after the preprocessor has finished its run).

It's true that the preprocessor allows you to conditionally compile code, but you cannot base those conditions on things which are known only at later translation stages.

Comment: Thank you.

so does that mean there is no way to check if a variable macro is defined?

Comment: @InstaFjelle - A macro and a variable are two very different things. I'm starting to second the notion you have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I suggest you ask another question on SO about your problem, instead of about what you think is the solution.

Comment: `#ifdef` checks if a macro is defined ... if that's not what you want, you need to explain it more clearly

Comment: basically i have to check if a variable is defined as a Macro. Specifically if a incoming process signal is a defined/valid signal. No i dont think i have.

I cant be more specific because it's for an exam, and i normally wouldnt ask here, but im taking a chance and assuming this is a syntax question rather than a specific solution question.

Comment: @InstaFjelle - I assure you, that you do. If you post a complete question that describes your situation (not "I need to do this to resolve a situation"). You may learn there is a better way. But please do so in a completely new post. If you edit your current one, it will make existing answers be off-topic, and that is bad SO etiquette.

Comment: @InstaFjelle In that case you don't want to know if the value of `i` corresponds to _any_ defined macro, but rather to one of the allowed signals. This is done by creating a list of all allowed signals as a `const` array, which you can then search through with the value of `i` as search key.

Comment: well the signals are already defined in a header file as macros. And yeah i would've done that if i was implementing it myself, but i doubt i have to change the current implementation

Comment: @InstaFjelle Anywhere in your program you could do `const int SIGNALS []  = { SOME_MACRO, SOME_OTHER_MACRO, YET_ANOTHER_MACRO }` regardless of who defined those macros or where they were defined. Preferably these should be sorted after their values, to enable faster search.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting a warning is because you redefine `DEFINED` in the event the macro `i` is not defined.  You need to define this macro entirely within an `#if`.

```
#ifndef i
#define DEFINED 0
#else
#define DEFINED 1
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor doesn't "know" C.  Barring special directives like `#error` and `#pragma`, it is much just a text-substitution system.

`#if((n)def)` only works for macros declared *with the preprocessor* with the `#define` keyword; C variables like `int i` are not macros.

To give you a better idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MYFORLOOP for(i = 0; i < 25; i++)

int main()
{
    int i;
    int data[25];
    MYFORLOOP
    {
        data[i] = i;
    }

    MYFORLOOP
    {
        printf("%d\n", data[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code is then preprocessed before it is actually compiled, so what the compiler actually "sees" is:

```
// < The contents of stdio.h, including any headers it includes itself >

int main()
{
    int i;
    int data[25];
    for(i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        data[i] = i;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", data[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The reason `#ifdef i` would fail is because the variable `i` is not a `#define` macro.